# Preserving PTS info when creating TS file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an MP4 to a TS file so that I can segment the file for iOS Streaming. I have a Video TS file (which has no audio) and a separate audio TS file. The problem I'm having is, sometimes the audio and the video would go out of sync. After doing some research, PTS has a very important role on this.

So, if I run `ffprobe -print_format csv -show_packets test.mp4` the result would be

> packet,video,0,0,0.000000,-7200,-0.080000,3600,0.040000,N/A,N/A,13154,1673,K
>   packet,video,0,3600,0.040000,-3600,-0.040000,3600,0.040000,N/A,N/A,9227,14827,_
>   packet,video,0,7200,0.080000,0,0.000000,3600,0.040000,N/A,N/A,8689,24054,_
>   packet,video,0,14400,0.160000,3600,0.040000,3600,0.040000,N/A,N/A,7730,32743,_

The 4th col is the PTS value and note that it starts with 0.

And if I convert the mp4 to a TS file with `ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -acodec libfaac -vcodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb test.ts` and then run `ffprobe -print_format csv -show_packets WG7855.ts`, I'll get

> packet,video,0,126000,1.400000,118800,1.320000,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,13204,564,K
>   packet,video,0,129600,1.440000,122400,1.360000,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,9233,14476,_
>   packet,video,0,133200,1.480000,126000,1.400000,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,8695,24816,_
>   packet,video,0,140400,1.560000,129600,1.440000,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,7736,34216,_

Note that the PTS starts with 126000. I've tried the `-copyts` arg and the PTS still starts with 126000.

Anyone out there who can help?

Comment: No idea about the PTS exactly, but if you need to segment for iOS streaming, why not use [the `segment` muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment)?

Comment: Yes! You're right, I've tried using ffmpeg and the PTS seems to be preserved! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks shlck! So what I did was

`ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -an -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list test.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -flags -global_header stream%05d.ts`

Seems that the ts file has all the timestamps preserved!